# UITableView offset on screen after adding custom segues

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard

I've recently had to change one of my view controllers from a table view controller to a normal view controller with a UITableView and upon doing that, I've had multiple issues.

I've finally gotten my data to populate my table but now my content is just off the screen and does not scroll or let me click a cell (looking like the table view starts at (-20, 0) or something):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I only have to elements to constrain, the UITableView and that little white View below it.

So I set the constraints to UITableView: Top: Superview, Trailing: Superview, Leading: Superview, Bottom: View + 2; and View: Width: 320, Height: 50, Bottom: Bottom Layout +2, Align Center X: Superview. Very simple constraints, but when I run I get this:

[image]

I don't understand why. In Main.Storyboard (Preview) I get this:

[image]

So according to the preview, it should be displaying perfect. Does anyone have any ideas why I'm getting this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `UINavigationBar` in your `UIViewController`. So you should probably set the top constraint of `UITableView` equals to zero to `TopLayoutGuide` rather than to `superView`.
It will set your TableView perfectly below the NavigationBar. Now it is behind the NavigationBar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So this only gave me a similar return

/Users/user/Desktop/Simulator Screen Shot Mar 30, 2016, 11.29.25 AM.png

Seems I can't drop a screenshot here but its the black screen again with the bottom of the white view only showing about 5 pixels in height

Comment: Can you please make sure you have set these constraints. 

`UITableView`: 
top: `TopLayoutGuide`, leading: `SuperView`, trailing: `SuperView`, bottom: view + 2

`UIView`:
width: 320, height: 50, bottom: `BottomLayoutGuide` + 2, `HorizontalCenter`

Comment: Yep, all those are correct. I think I'm going to rebuild the ViewController today, there just must be something missing..

Comment: Something interesting just happened. I put my ViewController as the initial view controller and everything was aligned perfect, just no nav bar or toolbar. The problem lies within the navigation controller.

Comment: Also I do have custom segues to and from this View Controller. Not sure if that's relevant but they have funky behavior sometimes..

Comment: Check my update above, its my segues. They aren't working correctly anymore, even though I'm using the same UIStoryboard class custom segues elsewhere in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere while troubleshooting this I saw one suggestion to try putting

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

into viewDidLoad and this single line of code ruined my life for a couple days. As upset as I am, I'm happy I found the issue. Hope this helps someone.